# How to save multiple steps in map function

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to create multiple samples, fit a model on each sample, and print the results.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x=rnorm(20, mean=5, sd=1),
  y=rnorm(20, mean=6, sd=1),
  weight = rnorm(20, mean=1, sd=0.2)
)

f <- function(data, var.x, var.y, n) {
  # select sample
  data_subset <- data %>% sample_n(n, weight = weight, replace = T) %>% select(all_of(var.x), all_of(var.y)) %>% drop_na()
  # fit model
  model <- lm(unlist(data_subset %>% select(y)) ~ unlist(data_subset %>% select(x))) 
  print(model)
}

f(data=dat, var.x="x", var.y="y", n=20)
```

Is there a way to save the dataset within a map function and fit the model? Here is an attempt:

```
    f <- function(data, var.x, var.y, n) {
map(seq_len(20),
      # select sample
      data_subset <- data %>% sample_n(n, weight = weight, replace = T) %>% select(all_of(var.x), all_of(var.y)) %>% drop_na()
      # fit model
      model <- lm(unlist(data_subset %>% select(y)) ~ unlist(data_subset %>% select(x))) 
      print(model)
)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # map
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20, mean=5, sd=1), y=rnorm(20, mean=6, sd=1), weight = rnorm(20, mean=1, sd=0.2) )
head(dat,3)
#          x        y    weight
# 1 6.370958 5.693361 1.0411997
# 2 4.435302 4.218692 0.9277885
# 3 5.363128 5.828083 1.1516326
out <- tibble(run = 1:20) %>%
  mutate(
    data = map(run, ~ sample_n(dat, size = 5, weight = weight, replace = TRUE)),
    mdl = map(data, ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .x)),
    smry = map(mdl, ~ summary(.x))
  )
```

At this point, three columns of `out` are list-columns,

```r
out
# # A tibble: 20 × 4
#      run data         mdl    smry      
#    <int> <list>       <list> <list>    
#  1     1 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  2     2 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  3     3 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  4     4 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  5     5 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  6     6 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  7     7 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  8     8 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#  9     9 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 10    10 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 11    11 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 12    12 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 13    13 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 14    14 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 15    15 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 16    16 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 17    17 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 18    18 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 19    19 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
# 20    20 <df [5 × 3]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
```

and we can access any of the individual elements using `[[`:

```r
out$data[[1]]
#           x        y    weight
# 1  4.721211 5.391074 1.1285799
# 2  4.893875 5.569531 1.0865636
# 3  6.370958 5.693361 1.0411997
# 4  6.370958 5.693361 1.0411997
# 5  4.866679 6.504955 1.0179521
# 6  4.893875 5.569531 1.0865636
# 7  6.511522 5.742731 0.8377214
# 8  5.404268 7.895193 0.7263438
# 9  4.715747 5.215541 1.1358578
# 10 4.866679 6.504955 1.0179521
# 11 6.511522 5.742731 0.8377214
# 12 6.370958 5.693361 1.0411997
# 13 2.343545 5.149092 1.0179666
# 14 6.511522 5.742731 0.8377214
# 15 5.632863 7.214675 0.8546590
# 16 6.370958 5.693361 1.0411997
# 17 5.632863 7.214675 0.8546590
# 18 4.905341 4.236837 1.2888203
# 19 4.435302 4.218692 0.9277885
# 20 2.343545 5.149092 1.0179666

out$data[1:2]
# [[1]]
#          x        y   weight
# 1 4.721211 5.391074 1.128580
# 2 4.893875 5.569531 1.086564
# 3 6.370958 5.693361 1.041200
# 4 6.370958 5.693361 1.041200
# 5 4.866679 6.504955 1.017952
# [[2]]
#          x        y    weight
# 1 4.893875 5.569531 1.0865636
# 2 6.511522 5.742731 0.8377214
# 3 5.404268 7.895193 0.7263438
# 4 4.715747 5.215541 1.1358578
# 5 4.866679 6.504955 1.0179521
out$mdl[1:2]
# [[1]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x  
#     6.11533     -0.06334  
# [[2]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x  
#      5.4066       0.1476  
out$smry[1:2]
# [[1]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .x)
# Residuals:
#        1        2        3        4        5 
# -0.42521 -0.23582 -0.01843 -0.01843  0.69788 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)  6.11533    1.59236   3.840   0.0311 *
# x           -0.06334    0.28966  -0.219   0.8409  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# Residual standard error: 0.4913 on 3 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.01569, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.3124 
# F-statistic: 0.04782 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.8409
# [[2]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .x)
# Residuals:
#       1       2       3       4       5 
# -0.5593 -0.6248  1.6910 -0.8870  0.3801 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)   5.4066     4.4193   1.223    0.309
# x             0.1476     0.8308   0.178    0.870
# Residual standard error: 1.224 on 3 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.01041, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.3195 
# F-statistic: 0.03155 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.8703
```

If you need to get more "complicated" than this (or if you want to anyway ...), look into the `broom` package and friends.

Note:

- I didn't functionize this, but it should be relatively simple to do that, my point here is to demonstrate doing things in *steps*, where the first such step is to store a list-column of "just data";

Comment: Very helpful. Is there a way to select columns in the model call? Since the data is a list, this doesn't seem to work: `mdl = purrr::map(data, ~ lm(.x %>% select(all_of(y)) ~ .x %>% select(all_of(x))), data=.x)`

Comment: Your model can be as simple or complex as you want based on the frames stored in the list-column.

Comment: I also just realized that all data frames are the same in the list. out$data[[1]] is the same as out$data[[2]]..

Comment: I see that and fixed it by `map`ping across `run`; it was a naive/stupid mistake on my part, please see the edit. (The only change was to `data = map(...)`, though this new version only samples 5 rows just to have a reduced sample output.)